# How to remove default package in maven project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

[image]

please help out how to remove default package in maven project in eclipse

Comment: Why do you want to do it?

Comment: When you do not create a package inside the src folder first and try to create class directly then eclipse create default package itself. You better delete by right-clicking on it and press on delete option. Then create package first and then create a class

Comment: The `default` package is the 'package without a package name'. It is there because you don't have any packages (i.e. subfolders) in the `src/main/java` folder. Create a package yourself and the `default` package will disappear

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking and select refresh on the project explorer. Make sure there is nothing in the default package first.